# Running total doesnt work Snowflake: error SQL compilation error:... is not a valid group by expression"

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with two column (close date and revenue amnount). I would like to calculate the cumulation aka running total of the revenue amount on Snowflake.

I have used the forma they have on their documentation but for some reason I keep getting this error. did someone else run into the issue and could you please help ?
[image]

```
select CLOSEDATE
,    sum(RECURRING_REVENUE_AMOUNTS) over (partition by CLOSEDATE order by CLOSEDATE rows between unbounded preceding and current row) running_total

from PHOENIX_PROD.BI_AL.OPPORTUNITY_OVERVIEW 
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like following (remove group by) -

```
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select closedate,sum(RECURRING_REVENUE_AMOUNTS) over (partition by closedate order
                                      by closedate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) running_total from
                                      OPPORTUNITY_OVERVIEW;
+------------+---------------+
| CLOSEDATE  | RUNNING_TOTAL |
|------------+---------------|
| 2021-03-26 |          2000 |
| 2021-03-21 |          2944 |
| 2021-03-25 |          3444 |
| 2021-03-20 |          2300 |
| 2021-03-24 |          2444 |
| 2021-03-17 |         10200 |
| 2021-03-23 |         44323 |
| 2021-03-19 |           300 |
| 2021-03-22 |          2333 |
| 2021-03-18 |         30200 |
+------------+---------------+
10 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.236s
```

Also refer to following which mentions partition is now always compatible with GROUP BY -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#general-tips